# When jQuery .attr('onclick') function return a event object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I am just debugging jQuery in FireBug and wonderig about the return value of

```
$('.a-selector').attr('onclick');
```

It turns out to be an `onclick(event)`, but I have read some code before and the author just uses it like this:

```
$('.a-selector').attr('onclick').replace(..., ...);
```

which means it can be treated as a String Object. But it reports an error when I use like this.

My jQuery version is 1.5.2. So I wonder when the jQuery changes the API and what is the best way to change the `onclick` event defined in the HTML.

Comment: It's not pretty but using ``attr('onClick')`` (capital C) will return it as string for you (at least in jQuery 1.4.2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When jQuery `.attr('onclick')` function return a event object?

In jQuery < 1.6. That's because prior to 1.6, `.attr()` did a mix between retrieving properties and attributes where it saw fit, newer versions removed that layer of witchery and now have proper methods for retrieving attributes ([`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)) and properties ([`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taL69/) demonstrating the above.

ps. BTW, it doesn't return an event object, but rather a function object that serves as event handler. `=]`

---

Also, 2 side notes: You should always upgrade your jquery to the latest version when viable (currently 1.8.3), it comes with more features, better performance and lots of bug fixes.

And you shouldn't really be using `onclick`s when you have jQuery, that goes against the Web 2.0 standards of separation of structure (html) and behavior (js) - jQuery itself provides cross-browser handler attaching with the methods [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (for jQuery 1.7+), and [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)/[`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)/[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to change the value of your onclick attribute of some element.

```
$('.a-selector').attr('onclick',''); // leave 2nd parameter blank if you want to remove its value
```

OR

```
$('.a-selector').attr('onclick','myfunc()');
```

############################### Edit

You can define your function as  below :

```
<script>
    function myfunc(){
        // Do stuff here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If I want to replace some words in the original function, how can I do this? Because as I describe in the post, some developer use "replace" function to treat it as a String object, it seems to be invalid in my jQuery library, as it is a event object. When does the changes make to the API?

Comment: i have modified my answer, kindly check it

Comment: Thanks, atif. Maybe what I want to do is a bad habit. But I have this kind of requirements, to keep the page work, just change a process function, but not change the original HTML.

Answer (score 0):

is it a possibility for you to reset the click event?

```
$('.a-selector').unbind('click').click(function() {
    // new function
});
```

to replace text in an javascript-code is normally not that what javascript should do. I think there is a much better solution possible.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean it's a bad habit to replace the original text in the HTML?

Comment: @RamLes No, I mean, that the string that represents a javascript-function should not be changed by .replace(). With replace you not replace the whole function but you are replacing parts of the function. That's not really good coding. Understand?