# Avoid multiple clicks on navigation bar html/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar on my html page. When a user clicks on an item,I change the contents of a div. The problem is if the user clicks on an item multiple times in quick succession the div's content too changes multiple times.
What I want is to change the content only one time when user clicks on an item quickly for multiple times.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I am using Bootstrap menu with onclick attribute to change some content accordingly.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this)">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this)">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this)">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this)">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function changeContent(item){
    //changing parent content-just for demo
    $(this).parent.html("Some content");
}
```

So if user click on a item multiple times quickly, the content will too change multiple times corresponding to each click.
I want the content to change just one time for multiple quick clicks.

Comment: Some more context would help. Show some HTML/js

Comment: You can do it with js/css. When you click on a tab add an "active" class (don't forget to remove it from the previously clicked tab) that will have the css rule "pointer-events: null".

Comment: @AmmarCSE I have added some code to make it more clear.

Comment: @suheb, what exactly is considered `multiple quick clicks`? Is it a certain timeframe?

Comment: @AmmarCSE Let's just say one click per second. This is to avoid user clicking like crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one click per second. This is to avoid user clicking like crazy.

1. Remove the inline `onclick` attributes with `removeAttr`
2. Use `setTimeout` to reset the attribute after x interval

```js
function changeContent(elem, num) {
  var that = $(elem);
  that.parent().append("Some content"+num);

  that.removeAttr('onclick');
  setTimeout(function() {
    that.attr('onclick', 'changeContent(this,'+num+')');
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 123)">Home</a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 432)">Menu 1</a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 545)">Menu 2</a> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 765)">Menu 3</a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But require the inline onclick attribute as I pass different values to `changeContent` for each item. Can you tell me how can I unbind/remove and then bind/add the onclick attribute with same value as before?

Comment: This is just what I need but I want to be able to set onclick attribute to same value as before. For eg

`<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 123)">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 432)">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 545)">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="changeContent(this, 765)">Menu 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>`

So for first item, I want to set onclick to same as before i.e `changeContent(this, 123)`. Is there any way I can save the value?

Comment: Thanks, that would work. But just out of curiosity. is there a way to get the value of onclick attribute like other attributes. For eg, `that.attr('click')` could return `changeContent(this, 123)`?

Comment: @suheb, what do you mean get the value? Which value?

Comment: @suheb, try `that.attr('onclick')`

Comment: `that.attr('onclick')` return onclick function like this:
`function onclick(event) { changeContent(this, 123); }`

Comment: Well, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933073/when-jquery-attronclick-function-return-a-event-object) explains why it return a function instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag and check if that has been set, do not trigger the function.

```
var userClicked = false;
onClick = function () {
if (!userClicked)
  // Perform the operation.
  displayTab();
else
  // Do nothing
  return false;
}
```